Disabling HDRI only for a specific render layer
I am working on an alien planet landscape still image with planets/moons in the background. For this, my scene is divided into 2 render layers and I need very different lighting for each of them.
Foreground layer - the majority of my scene. For this layer I need soft light coming from all sides, like sunlight diffused in the atmosphere. I intend to use a sun lamp and an HDRI.
Background layer - the other planets/moons. This layer need strong, hard light coming only from one direction, like sunlight in space. I intend to use a copy of the sun lamp with the copy rotation constraint.
This is what I want the planets/moons in the background to look like:

I think the best way to achieve that look would be to disable the HDRI for the background layer and only add the lighter values to the foreground in the compositor. But I don't know how to disable it only for the background without affecting the foreground layer, or whether it is possible at all. If it isn't possible, could you please suggest another way to achieve that effect? Thank you.

Have you tried including the Environment Lighting in your Render Passes and then using a Cryptomatte mask to selectively blend it into the scene with the other passes of the render? You can get every type of lighting completely separate in the render pass settings.

Hmm nvm, it seems like Environment lighting doesn't actually include the light information from the scene background. Despite that literally being what it says in the tooltip of the setting. lmao

Looks like light layers might be a good option.
